Ellis wormhole and energy conditions
I'm a bit puzzled about some calculations regarding the Ellis wormhole metric, prompted by Exercise 2.1(b) in Eric Poisson's "A Relativist's Toolkit". Suppose the metric has the form:
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dl^2 +(n^2+l^2)\Omega^2$$
Then, calculating the Ricci and Einstein tensors, and assuming EFE, one can easily show that this spacetime violates NEC, WEC, SEC and DEC at $l=0$. But when I have the metric in the following form (as in Poisson's book):
$$ds^2 = -dt^2+dl^2+r^2(l)d\Omega^2$$
with suitable restrictions on $r$, and calculate Ricci and Einstein tensors at $r_0 := r(0)$, I get $R_{\theta\theta} = 1$ and $R_{\phi\phi} = \sin^2(\theta)$ as only non-zero terms, and $G_{tt} = 1/r_0^2$ and $G_{ll} = -1/r_0^2$. In that case, all the above energy conditions are respected.
I don't know what's going on here: I checked the calculations with some software. What am I missing?

I find values of the Ricci and Einstein that you seem to be missing. Below I will share the code I ran in Mathematica which runs the tensor notation package xAct which you may be familiar with.
Results
From the code I find that the non-zero Riccis are
$$
R_{\ell\ell} = -\frac{2 r''(0)}{r_0}, \ \ R_{\Omega\Omega} = 1-r_0 r''(0)
$$
and the Einstein tensor gives me
$$
G_{tt} = \frac{1-2r_0 r''(0)}{r_0^2}, \ \ G_{\ell \ell} = \frac{-1}{r_0^2}, \ \ G_{\Omega\Omega} = r_0r''(0).
$$
Picking an arbitrary null  vector of $k^\mu = (1,-1,0)$ gives me
$$
G_{\mu\nu}k^\mu k^\nu = -\frac{2r''(0)}{r_0} <0.
$$
This implies that Null energy is broken implying that weak and strong energy conditions are also broken.
Code:
<<xAct`xTensor`
<<xAct`xCoba`(*Package*)

$PrePrint=ScreenDollarIndices;(*Was needed for nice printouts*)$CVVerbose=False;
DefManifold[M4,4,{\[Alpha],\[Beta],\[Delta],\[Gamma],\[Eta],\[Kappa],\[Lambda],\[Mu],\[Nu],\[Tau],\[Upsilon],\[Zeta]}];
(*4d manifold called M4,indices to be used*)

DefChart[wormhole,M4,{0,1,2,3},{t[],l[],\[Theta][],\[Phi][]},BasisColor->Blue]

DefScalarFunction/@{r};(*Auxiliary functions for metric*)

DefMetric[-1,metricg[-\[Alpha],-\[Beta]],CD,PrintAs->"g",SymbolOfCovD->{";","D"}]
(*Definition of the metric*)

MatrixForm[wormmetric = {
{-1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0},
{0,0,r[l[]]^2,0}
,{0,0,0,r[l[]]^2Sin[\[Theta][]]^2 }}]

MetricInBasis[metricg,-wormhole,wormmetric]
(*Explicit form for the metric*)
MetricCompute[metricg,wormhole,All]

(*Check christoffels*)
ChristoffelCDPDwormhole[\[Alpha],-\[Beta],-\[Gamma]]
ToBasis[wormhole][%]
MatrixForm[%//ComponentArray]
MatrixForm[ChrsWorm=%//ToValues]
MatrixForm[% //.{ l[]->0,r'[0]->0, r[0]->r0}//Simplify]

(*Check Ricci*)
RicciCD[-\[Alpha],-\[Beta]]
ToBasis[wormhole][%]
MatrixForm[%//ComponentArray]
MatrixForm[ricciWorm=%//ToValues]
MatrixForm[% //.{ l[]->0,r'[0]->0, r[0]->r0}//Simplify]

(*Check Einstein*)
EinsteinCD[-\[Alpha],-\[Beta]]
ToBasis[wormhole][%]
%//ComponentArray
MatrixForm[EinWorm=%//ToValues]
MatrixForm[% //.{ l[]->0,r'[0]->0, r[0]->r0}//Simplify]


DefTensor[k[\[Alpha]],M4]
k[\[Alpha]]k[\[Beta]]EinsteinCD[-\[Alpha],-\[Beta]]
ToBasis[wormhole][%]
%//TraceBasisDummy
StrongEnergy=%//ToValues
%//.{k[{0,wormhole}]->1,k[{1,wormhole}]->-1,k[{2,wormhole}]->0,k[{3,wormhole}]->0}
% //.{ l[]->0,r'[0]->0, r[0]->r0}//Simplify

